# vuex- state returned as function or object literal

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I ran into a problem the other day, and asked the great stack community for a solution.

#### The problem:

I nested the same module in other modules but I was defining state in this way:

```
state: {
  // some state here
}
```

What was happening is all of my modules despite seeming being nested under disparate modules all shared the same state.

#### The solution

```
state() {
  return {
    // state here instead
  }
}
```

The solution is to have a function return state rather than define it as an object literal. The why somewhat makes sense. Here are my questions

#### New questions

1. What is happening under the hood of the store when state is defined as an object literal versus a function returning an object literal?
2. Why would you ever not use the function version? It seems like easily the default choice, but even in [vuex docs for `modules`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html), they opt to show state as an object literal.

Comment: Since vuex is a store management it make sense for the state to have a single insane, remember we are saving and retrieving data from vuex so the state has to be an object, otherwise a function would return new values everytime

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### **tl;dr** The reason for using a function is [**Module Reuse**](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html#module-reuse).

---

> What is happening under the hood of the store when state is defined as an object literal versus a function returning an object literal?

For that, better [check under the hood](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/v3.0.1/dist/vuex.js#L317-L319):

```
var Store = function Store (options) {
  // ...
  var state = options.state; if ( state === void 0 ) state = {};
  if (typeof state === 'function') {
    state = state() || {};
  }
```

The code above, as you can see, checks if a `state` was provided. If not, it assigns an empty object (`{}`) as initial `state`.

Next it checks if `state` was a `function`. If it was, it executes it and assigns to `state` what it returned. If it returned `undefined` (or any *falsy* value) it, again, assigns to `state` the empty object `{}`.

So that's the difference between providing `state` as an object or function: if one was provided, it is executed. If an object is provided, it is assigned *directly*.

> Why would you ever not use the function version? It seems like easily the default choice, but even in vuex docs for modules, they opt to show state as an object literal.

In general, yes, the object version may be more common, because you typically only declare the `store` object (and its `state`) once and just use it in your Vue instance.

A use case for the `state` function, otoh, is [**Module Reuse**](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html#module-reuse):

> ### Module Reuse
>
> Sometimes we may need to create multiple instances of a module, for
>   example:
>
> - Creating multiple stores that use the same module (e.g. [To avoid
>     stateful singletons](https://ssr.vuejs.org/en/structure.html#avoid-stateful-singletons) in the SSR when the runInNewContext option is
>     false or 'once');
> - Register the same module multiple times in the same
>     store.

Another possible case would be if you declared a Vuex module **just once** and attempted to use it **more than one time under different namespaces**.

As the examples above are similar, here's a demo (of the module case) to illustrate the problem:

```js
const personModule = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {name: "name"},
  mutations: {
   changeName(state, data) { state.name = data }
  }
}
const myStore = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  modules: {
    aliceNamespace: personModule,
    bobNamespcace: personModule
  }
});
new Vue({
  store: myStore,
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    this.changeAlicesName("Alice");
    this.changeBobsName("Bob");
  },
  computed: {
    ...Vuex.mapState('aliceNamespace', {alicesName: 'name'}),
    ...Vuex.mapState('bobNamespcace', {bobsName: 'name'})
  },
  methods: {
    ...Vuex.mapMutations('aliceNamespace', {changeAlicesName: 'changeName'}),
    ...Vuex.mapMutations('bobNamespcace', {changeBobsName: 'changeName'})
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>Alice's name: {{ alicesName }}</p>
  <hr>
  <p>Bob's name: {{ bobsName }}</p>
  <hr>
  <button @click="changeAlicesName('Eve')">Change Alice's Name</button>
</div>
```

As you can see, when we use the state, the same object is assigned as `state` of both modules. The effect of this is when we edit a module, the other is affected. In reality, they may be two different modules, but **their `state` is just one same object**.

In the example below, on the other hand, when we declare `state` as a function, we can reuse the module declaration freely, as many times as we want:

```js
const personModule = {
  namespaced: true,
  state() {                     // changed to a function
    return {name: "name"}       // changed to a function
  },                            // changed to a function
  mutations: {
   changeName(state, data) { state.name = data }
  }
}
const myStore = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  modules: {
    aliceNamespace: personModule,
    bobNamespcace: personModule
  }
});
new Vue({
  store: myStore,
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    this.changeAlicesName("Alice");
    this.changeBobsName("Bob");
  },
  computed: {
    ...Vuex.mapState('aliceNamespace', {alicesName: 'name'}),
    ...Vuex.mapState('bobNamespcace', {bobsName: 'name'})
  },
  methods: {
    ...Vuex.mapMutations('aliceNamespace', {changeAlicesName: 'changeName'}),
    ...Vuex.mapMutations('bobNamespcace', {changeBobsName: 'changeName'})
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>Alice's name: {{ alicesName }}</p>
  <hr>
  <p>Bob's name: {{ bobsName }}</p>
  <hr>
  <button @click="changeAlicesName('Eve')">Change Alice's Name</button>
</div>
```

Because `state` is a function, it will generate a different `state` instance for each module, working as expected all the way.

Comment: EDIT: Have updated the answer, adding a link to the Module Reuse part of the Vuex official docs (where they mention the function explictly).

Comment: Thank you! Would you find an arrow function more convenient in this case when no `this` is referenced, or what is your preferred way and why if I may ask?

Comment: @Artfaith I think the way to go is to decide this as a team and follow it along. For instance, I have worked simultaneously on projects for two distinct teams and one favored `function`s and other favored arrow functions. We all have our preferences, but I guess in the end of the day we must be flexible. Anyway, since you mentioned preference, I guess I should tell my personal one, and, in that case, I slightly favor arrow functions, simply because it is shorter in general and because I found that teams where the rule was "arrow functions everywhere" were easier to adhere to