# How to use functions in Vuex state creation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to set part of my state using a getter which I later define

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state : {
    a : 1,
    b : getters.multiply(a)
  },
  getters : {
    multiply : (state) => (param) => return param * 2
  },
})
```

This is not allowed as the getters are not ready (I think).

The docs do state that the Vuex state property can take a function to create the data - but I have not seen any examples, does the full state need to be initialised by function call or some props.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally `getters` is method to get state data. It should not be 2 ways.
In above example, you can do:

```
const multiply = (params) => params * 2
const INIT_VALUE = 1

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state : {
    a : INIT_VALUE,
    b : multiply(INIT_VALUE)
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but this sets the value outside, you could not pass `a` in directly?

Comment: Why do want to pass a directly? If b only depend on a, you can create another getters (getB for example) for it.

Comment: The above example was just for reference the actual app code is much more involved. `b` cannot contain a getter as far as I am aware?? The issue is `a` is set after the store is created and is changed, `b` depends on `a` but they need to be separate objects due to state change.

Comment: If you need to keep `a` and `b` separately, then when you change `a` value (for example you change in a `mutations`), you can change `b` value also

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50432819/5113030) by [@ittus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303610/ittus).

You might want a more independent "state initialization function" which would return a fairly isolated instance of an initial Vuex state object. This would allow a Vuex [module](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html) reuse [^1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49566359/5113030) if required. For example:

```js
const INIT_VALUE = 1;

// Functions

const multiply = (a, b = 2) => Number(a * b);

// const defaultState = a => ({ /* ... */ });

function defaultState(a) {
  return {
    a,
    b: multiply(a)
  }
}

// State

const state = defaultState(INIT_VALUE);

// Store

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  state
});
```

---

Regarding "arrow" vs "regular" function for `defaultState`: [Vue JS: Difference of data() { return {} } vs data:() => ({ })](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980865/vue-js-difference-of-data-return-vs-data).